# g_random_int() returns negative numbers

Tags: c, glib

This is the documentation of g_random_int() function from GLib:

```
 guint32 g_random_int (void);
 Return a random guint32 equally distributed over the range [0..2^32-1].
```

But the following code returns negative numbers:

```
 for (i=0; i< 10; ++i)
     printf("Random: %d\n", g_random_int());
```

Something obvious that I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `printf`-format string.

`%d` is the format-specifier for signed integers.

You are effectively reading the unsigned integer as if it was signed.

Use `%u` instead :) Then your code becomes

```
 for (i=0; i< 10; ++i)
     printf("Random: %u\n", g_random_int());
```

Here is a reference for the various format-specifiers in C: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

**EDIT**

I believe this is the passage in the C99 standard that describes the case of undefined behavior for the formatted output-functions, that @[12431234123412341234123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6082851/12431234123412341234123) refers to:

> In a call to one of the formatted output functions, a precision appears with a conversion specifier other than those described (7.19.6.1, 7.24.2.1).

.. or maybe it's this:

> An invalid conversion specification is found in the format for one of the formatted input/output functions, or the strftime or wcsftime function (7.19.6.1, 7.19.6.2, 7.23.3.5, 7.24.2.1, 7.24.2.2, 7.24.5.1).

See this page for more cases that are undefined behavior: https://gist.github.com/Earnestly/7c903f481ff9d29a3dd1

**EDIT2**

See the comment section for a much more intelligent discussion of the issue.

Comment: This is technical UB. (using a format specifier with a different signess)

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I have updated the answer. Is this the UB-case you are referring to?

Comment: From the C11 Standard Working Draft section 7.21.6.1 p9, I found this in describing the `fprintf` function: *If  a  conversion  specification  is  invalid,  the  behavior  is  undefined. If  any argument  is not  the  correct  type  for  the  corresponding  conversion  specification,  the  behavior  is undefined.*

Comment: @MortenJensen I refer to section 7.15.1.1:2 _...or if
type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined..._ But i have to correct myself, it is not UB when the value can be represented in both types and only the signess is different.

Comment: However i do not know a single implementation where the wrong signess causes problems. (except from printing unexpected values, like in the question)

Comment: And in 7.19.6.1:9 it is defined for `fprintf()`: _... If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined._

Comment: I don't think Glib is compatible with 16 bit system so the int is at least 32 bit, if the range is 0-0x7fffffff the conversion from guint32 to int should not overflow and so produce a negative number. Under which machine did you get negative numbers?

Comment: @FredianoZiglio I take the range `[0..2^32-1]` to mean `[0..(2^32)-1]` and not `[0..2^31]` - otherwise why not just write 2^31 :) So the range is 0-0xFFFFFFFF and not 0-0x7FFFFFFF as you suggest, which explains the overflow when (implicitly) converted to signed.